# pouchdb promise to fancytree

Tags: javascript, promise, pouchdb, fancytree

I am trying to supply a promise to the source option of fancytree. The promise is supposed to do 4 things:

1. Get the docs from the pouchdb database (using promise allDocs())
2. Generate tree roots from the db content - synchronously
3. Subscribe to changes in the db (using changes() feed)
4. return the tree roots from 2. to the source.

I am obviously doing something wrong. Parts 1. and 2. of the promise are being executed, but the rest is ignored. I suspect I have misunderstood promise chaining with mixed synchronous and asynchronous behaviour. I would welcome suggestions as to what I am doing wrong.

So essentially this is my code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#tree").fancytree(
        source: function fetchDocsAndSubscribe () {
            return pouch.allDocs({...})
            .then (function (docs) {
                return generateRootNodes (docs) // sync
            })
            .then (function (rootNodes) {
                pouch.changes({live: true,....})
                .on('change', function (change) {
                    onChange (change);
                })
                .on('error', function (error) {
                    console.log("Change error: " + error);
                });
                return rootNodes;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {console.log('error: ' + err);
                return;
            })
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies - the promise chain was fine. I had a fault in my generateRootNodes function that was aborting the promise chain